My app is rejected in play console due to below android auto category issue
My app is rejected due to category related issue in android auto.
Play console rejected error :
Issue found: Category not permitted
At this time, we are only accepting apps within the Media, short form Messaging, or categories supported by the Android for Cars App Library. Media apps that use TSS engine readout for content are not permitted at this time.
The app must not include features outside the app types intended for cars. For more information, see Supported app categories.
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
            android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" /> 



 <service
              android:name=".embervoip.CarService"
              android:exported="true"
           >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
                 <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.CALLING" />
             </intent-filter>
         </service>

automotive_app_desc.xml file is
uses name="template"
How to solve it and upload in playconsole.

It is unclear what your question is. If we guess that the question is "how can I fix my Play Store entry?", questions about app distribution channels are off-topic.
